# Why does hslogger give this error message? : hPutStr: illegal operation (handle is closed)

Tags: haskell, logging

I must not know how to use hslogger correctly. I get this error message:

```
hsloggerTest1: test.log: hPutStr: illegal operation (handle is closed)
```

When I run this code in hsloggerTest1.hs

```
-- hslogger
import System.Log.Logger         ( Priority(ERROR), addHandler
                                 , errorM, updateGlobalLogger
                                 )
import System.Log.Handler        (close)
import System.Log.Handler.Simple (fileHandler)


main :: IO ()
main = do
  let logger   = "main"
      fileName = "test.log"

  h1 <- fileHandler fileName ERROR
  putStrLn "opened file1"
  updateGlobalLogger logger $ addHandler h1
  putStrLn "will write1"
  errorM logger "writing 1"
  putStrLn "did write1"
  close h1
  putStrLn "closed file1"

  h2 <- fileHandler fileName ERROR
  putStrLn "opened file2"
  updateGlobalLogger logger $ addHandler h2
  putStrLn "will write2"
  errorM logger "writing 2"
--  putStrLn "did write2"
--  close h2
--  putStrLn "closed file2"
```

The contents of test.log is:

```
writing 1
writing 2
```

What am I doing wrong?  (Or is this an hslogger bug?)  Thanks.

By the way, I've fixed the problem in my real code with a little restructuring. However, I'm still curious why what I did above was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont see an interface to remove a handler, therefore to make the above code work, I have used setHandlers and override the earlier handler if this helps your usecase.

```
import System.Log.Logger         ( Priority(ERROR), addHandler, setHandlers
                             , errorM, updateGlobalLogger
                             )
import System.Log.Handler        (close)
import System.Log.Handler.Simple (fileHandler)
import Data.Time.Clock

main :: IO ()
main = do
let logger   = "main"
   fileName = "test.log"
h1 <- fileHandler fileName ERROR
putStrLn "opened file1"
updateGlobalLogger logger $ setHandlers[h1]
putStrLn "will write1"
c1 <- getCurrentTime
errorM logger $ "writing 1 " ++ (show c1)
putStrLn "did write1"
close h1
putStrLn "closed file1"

h2 <- fileHandler fileName ERROR
putStrLn "opened file2"
updateGlobalLogger logger $ setHandlers[h2]
putStrLn "will write2"
c <- getCurrentTime
errorM logger ("writing 2 " ++ (show c))
putStrLn "did write2"
--  close h2  
--  putStrLn "closed file2"
```

The contents of the log file:
    
    `writing 12014-02-27 23:03:35.0594493 UTC
    writing 2 2014-02-27 23:03:35.0754502 UTC`

Update:
This is how I interpret the http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hslogger-1.0.7/docs/System-Log-Logger.html doc:  if the root hierarchy is the same then the same set of handlers are searched for. In order for me to understand the api, here is another version:

```
-- hslogger
import System.Log.Logger         ( Priority(ERROR), addHandler
                             , errorM, updateGlobalLogger
                             )
import System.Log.Handler        (close)
import System.Log.Handler.Simple (fileHandler)


main :: IO ()
main = 
 do
    putStrLn("This will work because the hierarchies are different")
    mainWithLoggerPair ("main", "main2")
    putStrLn("______________________________________________________")
    putStrLn("This will fail because the root logger is returned from the tree map")
    mainWithLoggerPair ("main", "main.sub")


mainWithLoggerPair (logger1, logger2) = do
  let  fileName = "test.log"
  h1 <- fileHandler fileName ERROR
  putStrLn "opened file1"
  updateGlobalLogger logger1 $ addHandler h1
  putStrLn "will write1"
  errorM logger1 "writing 1"
  putStrLn "did write1"
  close h1
  putStrLn "closed file1"

  h2 <- fileHandler fileName ERROR
  putStrLn "opened file2"
  updateGlobalLogger logger2 $ addHandler h2
  putStrLn "will write2"
  errorM logger2 "writing 2"
  putStrLn "did write2"
  close h2
  putStrLn "closed file2"
```

`
In the above case when the same logger hierarchy is being used the write fails because we still have the issue of a handler not being removed when the underlying file handle was closed.

I tried to browse the code on the site to get a better understanding of the library:

```
type LogTree = Map.Map String Logger
```

This tree is maintained based on the logger strings for example 
"a.b.c" belong to the tree under "a" but loggers "l1" and "l2" are different loggers. I hope that this helps shed some additional light on the api.
Now, lets consider the current test case: 
The name of the logger never changed, this implies that the map will find the earlier logger and return the existing logger instance (equivalent haskell term?) with a handler in the list of handlers referring to the closed file handle.

It would have been intuitive to present a removeHandler interface to handle the above test case.

Comment: I agree your solution will work.  It's still not clear to me why my approach resulted in an error condition.